# Nebentypus of contragredient representation

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, local-field

Let $k$ be a local non-archimedean field with ring of integers $\cal O$ and maximal ideal $\frak p$.

Let $\pi$ be an irreducible admissible $\infty$-dimensional representation of $\text{GL}_2(k)$ with central character $\varepsilon$. We know from a classical paper of Casselman that there exists a largest ideal ${\frak p}^s\subset\cal O$ such that the subspace of vectors $v\in\pi$ such that
$$
(*)\qquad\qquad\pi(\gamma)v=\varepsilon(a)v\qquad
\text{for all }\gamma=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{array}
\right)\in K_0({\frak p}^s)
$$
is non-empty and in fact one-dimensional (newvector).

Here $K_0({\frak p}^n)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{array}
\right)\in{\rm GL}_2(\cal O)$ such that $c\equiv0\bmod{\frak p}^n$.

Incidentally, if (*) occurs then $\varepsilon$ needs to be a character of $K_0({\frak p}^s)$ and this happens only if $s$ is greater then the conductor of $\varepsilon$.

Now consider the contragredient representation $\check\pi$. We know that $\check\pi\simeq\pi\otimes\varepsilon^{-1}(\det)$. It is very easy to check that the central character of $\check\pi$ is $\varepsilon^{-1}$. Indeed
$$
\check\pi(zI_2)=\pi(zI_2)\varepsilon^{-1}(\det(zI_2))=
\varepsilon(z)\varepsilon^{-1}(z^2)=\varepsilon^{-1}(z).
$$
So one would expect, by Casselman's theory, a newvector in $\check\pi$ with character $\varepsilon^{-1}$. But, if $v\in\pi$ is the newvector
$$
\check\pi(\gamma)v=\pi(\gamma)\varepsilon^{-1}(det(\gamma))v=
\varepsilon(a)\varepsilon^{-1}(ad)v=\epsilon^{-1}(d)v
$$
and $\epsilon^{-1}(a)\neq\epsilon^{-1}(d)$. Note that 
$\varepsilon^{-1}(det(\gamma))=\varepsilon^{-1}(ad-bc)=\varepsilon^{-1}(ad)$ because $ad\in\cal O^\times$ and $\varepsilon$ is trivial on $1+{\frak p}^s$.

So,what is going on?

Comment: Your mistake is to assume that the new vector of $\pi \otimes \epsilon^{-1}$ is necessarily the same vector as the new vector of $\pi$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler : I understand that the newvector in $\pi$ does not coincide with the newvector in $\pi\otimes\varepsilon^{-1}$. What surprises me, though, is that there are vectors (different from the newvector) on which $K_0({\frak p}^s)$ still acts as character.

Comment: This is how it always works, actually. If you look at the invariants under the subgroup $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \bmod \mathfrak{p}^n$ then it will be normalized by $\begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ 0 & * \end{pmatrix} \bmod \mathfrak{p}^n$ and you get a bunch of different characters of the quotient showing up -- I think it's actually *all* characters of the appropriate conductor that induce $\varepsilon$ on the centre.